# Path-integral vs quantum amplitude for a chain of events

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

The path integral sums over $e^{iS}$ where the action S is the integral of the Lagrangian density, and each infinitesimal term corresponds to the quantum amplitude corresponding to the particular path (or rather, spacetime configuration of fields or "histories" that go into the Lagrangian integral).

But these terms will all be of unit magnitude and therefore each individual term doesn't seem to correspond to quantum amplitudes that can be squared to get a corresponding probability, only finite sums of the "histories" can accumulate to any (complex) value.

Am I doing some terminology error here? I guess I'm intuitively trying to think of a single infinitesimal term of the path integral corresponding to for example a chain of events normally used in perturbative expansions like "electron goes from A to B, emits a photon" etc. and which typically gets a non-unit-magnitude amplitude. But I guess this is not the right way to see it.

I know how the argument for the path integral form itself arises (from the concept of stationary phase, classical correspondence etc).

Comment: *"each infinitesimal term corresponds to the quantum amplitude corresponding to the particular path"* [citation needed] This sounds like a phrase that Feynman and others like to use to explain the path integral to laymen, but I don't see how that is supported by the formalism, or indeed what the "quantum amplitude corresponding to the particular path" is even supposed to mean rigorously, given that there *are* no definite paths in quantum mechanics.

Comment: That's exactly my issue I guess, that it's described like that in most expositions of the path integral formalism. I wanted to figure out where that idea comes from. At least in a perturbative formalism the concept is applicable when building each term right (if you define "path" to be a momentum space view of each term or do the expansion in position space).